# Lower current through different transistors

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm building a small PIR driven circuit, currently a simple PIR activated light, and for this I'm using an RGB LED strip as I had it lying around from another project.  The diagram that follows works fine with a 2N7000 transistor.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Looking at its datasheet, the 2N7000 can only handle a small current which won't be enough when I increase the length of the LED strip - it'll need to handle something like 1A.  I tried replacing the 2N7000 with some MOSFETs I had lying around, an IRF540 and a ST 16NF06FP.  With either of these, the LEDs light but only  dimly.  Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Look up the voltage threshold of the various MOSFETs.

Comment: Schematics are generally more useful than the wiring diagram.  Fritzing can provide both.  Please post the schematic instead of the wiring diagram.

Comment: First thing I was was that cartoon.  If you don't take your problem seriously, why should I?  -1 for not supplying a schematic, and closing because since I can't get past the insulting cartoon, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Apologies for that, I could indeed have posted the schematic and will do so in future.  We all have to start somewhere, right?

Comment: see IRFZ46 , it's good price (about 0.6 $), 50 V , 50 A and 0.025 ohm on resistance mosfet.

Comment: Circuit diagram added from eagle.

Comment: 1: If you want others than the author of a post to see a comment you have to address it to them.  I only saw your reply here by chance.  2: It's good that you added a schematic, and I undid my -1, but that cartoon is still there, still making your post annoying, still making you look like a weenie who's not worth spending volunteer time to help.  Get that thing out of my face! You have to start somewhere, but not necessarily here.  Communicating circuits with schematics is a prerequisite here.  You wouldn't go to the math site and not expect to have to use equations.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, @OlinLathrop - Fritzing output now replaced with schematic.

Comment: @Merlin83b. Even I was lambasted by Olin in my early days. Take it as you take an opinion from your teacher. You will only end up more wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The V<sub>GS</sub> problem:

The 2n7000 has a ***V<sub>GS</sub> (Voltage Gate to Source)** of 3 Volts Max. Meaning it is a low logic level Mosfet, and will have it's lowest ***R<sub>DS(on)</sub> (Resistance Drain to Source when On)*** at that voltage or above. It's great for a 3.3V signal.

The IRF540 has a much higher V<sub>GS</sub>, nearly 10 Volts for lowest R<sub>DS(on)</sub>. It's V<sub>GS</sub> ***Threshold*** is listed as min 2.0 ~ max 4.0 Volts. This Threshold dictates the lowest voltage that will even turn it on (Passing just 250µA). ***Always assume the Max spec, 3.3V won't even turn it on.*** At Room Temperature, it won't be at all. Looking at it's V<sub>GS</sub> graph, at 5V, it will still pass around 10 Amps. Not the lowest resistance or maximum current capabilities, but fine for some folks. It's the go-to resistor for the Arduino crowd (Arduino Uno being 5V logic).

I can't find the 16NF06FP, but a STP16NF06 has similar stats to the IRF540.

---

### The PIR Module:

The Sensor you have is a BIS00001 based PIR controller module. It's operating at 3.3V, and it's output is directly controlled by the BIS00001. It has limited current sourcing, and is ***Active High***. It's output goes high when motion is sensed.

---

### Driving it

Since you want to control a low side, N-Channel mosfet or transistor, you could hook it up directly and it will turn on the Load/LEDs when the sensor sees motion. ***But since you need to drive a larger Mosfet, you need an in-between. And since that in-between is also a low side, N-Channel mosfet or transistor, you will need to invert the logic.***

You will need 3 transistors or Mosfets total. The first two are just logic level switching, the last being the power driver. Q1 and M1 can both be transistors, or mosfets. I used one 2n3904 and one 2N7000, but you can replace them with any small switching transistor or n-fet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKkgvl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, you can replace it with a P-Channel Mosfet and one transistor, no logic inverting needed. Again, the 2n7000 can work instead of the 2n3904 if you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdeG5Z.png)</sup>